# SOAP request without server-side

Tags: javascript, html, soap

I'm making a website that checks the European VAT numbers, using the SOAP request on the official website of [European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/#/technical-information)

I just created a script on VSCode that works perfectly inside the Terminal with Node.js
Using the "soap" node package.

The moment i try it in the browser it obviously doesn't work.

I tryed using other packages like "node-soap" and "jquery.soap" (i saw somewhere that this package should work, but i think it was years ago) with no success.

Is there a way to be able to make it work without the need for a server-side?

const soap = require('soap');

```
const url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl';
const args = [
    {
        countryCode: 'SE',
        vatNumber: '556243997501'
    },
    {
        countryCode: 'IE',
        vatNumber: '6388047V'
    }
]
;

let results = [];
let index = 0;
args.forEach((arg) => {
   
        soap.createClient(url, (err, client) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            client.checkVat(arg, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                let obj = {
                    countryCode: arg.countryCode,
                    vatNumber: arg.vatNumber,
                    requestDate: result.requestDate,
                    valid: result.valid,
                    name: result.name,
                    address: result.address
                }
                results.push(obj);
                console.log(results);                 
            });
        });
    index++;
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what error(s) you're getting. At first glance, this looks like a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong URL, so if you switch it will works.

From

```
'https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl'
```

To

```
'https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService.wsdl'
```

Test Result

```
$ node get-vat.js
[
  {
    countryCode: 'IE',
    vatNumber: '6388047V',
    requestDate: Invalid Date,
    valid: true,
    name: 'GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED',
    address: '3RD FLOOR, GORDON HOUSE, BARROW STREET, DUBLIN 4'
  }
]
[
  {
    countryCode: 'IE',
    vatNumber: '6388047V',
    requestDate: Invalid Date,
    valid: true,
    name: 'GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED',
    address: '3RD FLOOR, GORDON HOUSE, BARROW STREET, DUBLIN 4'
  },
  {
    countryCode: 'SE',
    vatNumber: '556243997501',
    requestDate: Invalid Date,
    valid: true,
    name: 'IKEA Components AB',
    address: 'BOX 600,SÖDRA RINGVÄGEN 4 \n343 24 ÄLMHULT'
  }
]
```

## Update

Demo code
#1 save as `get-vat.js`

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService.wsdl';
const args = [
    {
        countryCode: 'SE',
        vatNumber: '556243997501'
    },
    {
        countryCode: 'IE',
        vatNumber: '6388047V'
    }
];

let results = [];
let index = 0;
args.forEach((arg) => {
    soap.createClient(url, (err, client) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        client.checkVat(arg, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let obj = {
                countryCode: arg.countryCode,
                vatNumber: arg.vatNumber,
                requestDate: result.requestDate,
                valid: result.valid,
                name: result.name,
                address: result.address
            }
            results.push(obj);
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
    index++;
});
```

#2 install soap and run it

```
npm install soap
node get-vat.js
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show me how you did it? I can't manage to make it work

Comment: @AndreSantos, I updated my answer step by step. I realized you want to it without server. It means you want to your own local Web server?